# Force Shutdown/Reboot

Tags: c#, vb.net, pinvoke, shutdown, reboot

How can I force the windows computer to shutdown by using the P/Invoke Declaration for ExitWindowsEx in VB.Net?
I am not talking about `Process.Start("shutdown -s -f- -t 0")`
I know there is way to do the same thing using the Windows API.
How can I force a shutdown/reboot?

Comment: The third answer in the linked duplicate question shows how to do it with `ExitWindowsEx`.